# How to insert values into a table from the result of a SELECT statement SQL

Tags: sql

I've got two tables, one called `PLAYERS` with this structure:

```
PLAYERS (name, team, goals, cod)
```

and another one called `NEW_PLAYERS` with this structure:

```
NEW_PLAYERS (name, team, goals)
```

I want to insert values from `NEW_PLAYERS` into `PLAYERS` setting the value 1 for the register `cod` of all of `NEW_PLAYERS`.

I thought this code could work but it doesn't.

```
INSERT INTO PLAYERS (name, team, goals, cod) 
VALUES ((SELECT name, team, goals FROM NEW_PLAYERS), 1);
```

Does anyone have a better option?

Comment: See this [very recent question & answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71325876/15332650)

Comment: Why do you have two such similar tables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were almost there. Try this.

```
INSERT INTO PLAYERS(name,team,goals,cod) 
SELECT name,team,goals,1 FROM NEW_PLAYERS
```

Answer (score 0):

use  `INSERT ... SELECT` not `INSERT ... VALUES`

```
INSERT INTO PLAYERS(name,team,goals,cod)
SELECT n.name
     , n.team
     , n.goals
     , 1 AS cod
  FROM NEW_PLAYERS n
 ORDER BY 1,2,3
```